# startService on Android 9

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

According to android documentation from version api v26 we can not use startService. So we should check the version and if version is older than Oreo then we execute startService otherwise startForegroundService. From the other hand I installed on my android smarthpone (android PIE 9) old application "phone counter on screen" which works fine. Then I decompile that project and I found that this app use only startService, so for me that old app shouldn't work. Based on that app, I build my own project, which has exactly the same patterns (run service by startService which register and unregister receiver which listens for action android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON). Application run, service started, but when I kill app from menu, then service also has been killed.

**Why some old application from google store can use very old and not permitted code on one of latest android version?**

Answer (score 0):

> According to android documentation from version api v26 we can not use startService

That is not what [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#back-all) states. It states:

> The `startService()` method now throws an `IllegalStateException` if **an app targeting Android 8.0** tries to use that method in a situation when it isn't permitted to create background services.

(emphasis added, and I will come back to that shortly)

> So we should check the version and if version is older than Oreo then we execute startService otherwise startForegroundService.

If you will be starting the service from the background, that is indeed required... for new apps.

> Why some old application from google store can use very old and not permitted code on one of latest android version?

Because that app has not been updated in years, apparently. It still has a `targetSdkVersion` below 26. `targetSdkVersion` exists to tell Android what API level the app has adapted to. In this case, with a `targetSdkVersion` below 26, Android knows that the app is not set up to use `startForegroundService()`, so Android behaves a bit more like older versions of Android.

Bear in mind that if you distribute through the Play Store (and some other distribution channels), new and updated apps cannot have that old of a `targetSdkVersion`. For example, right now (2020-03-14), the Play Store requires a `targetSdkVersion` of 28 or higher.